# Button in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'd like to add UIButton to my UIViewController. I have a UIPageViewController on all screen. When I'm trying to add this button... there is no button on the sreen visible. What do I do wrong?

CODE:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(setButtonVisibleClose:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Zamknij widok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview: button];


    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    BasicViewViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    [initialViewController setImageViewToDisplay];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Try adding the button last, i.e. after [self.pageController didMoveToParent...].. My guess is that its covered by the subviews you added.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It was covered. Now it works ok.

Comment: Ok great, I'll add that as an 'official' answer in case anyone comes by later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is likely that you added the button as a subview *first*, and then created the page controller and added it's view "on top of" the button. Subviews added first are always by default placed *under* subviews that are added later.

If you move the button creation code to after the page controller code in that method, your button should appear on top of the page controller.